# Python requests: How to set HTML format `request payload` part in POST request?

Tags: python, python-requests

This is Google Chrome network tab:

[image]

As you can see here, **Request Payload** part is `HTML` format, not dictionary(key, value) format.

So I have a problem setting `data` part, which is dictionary type, of `requests` library.

How can I set the payload in this case?

Comment: Browsers often pretty print stuff in dev tools. Are you sure you see **raw** value?

Comment: PS Also this is not HTML, but XML. XML is very generic, and can be used to represent any data.

Comment: @przemo_li. Thanks! I didn't notice that it is `XML` ! That thread solved my issues!